# Is it safe to remove vent and cap off unused drain

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, venting

I am in the process of renovating my kitchen and removed a wall. I discovered a closed off drain and a vent that goes through the ceiling.

There does not appear to be anything else tied into the vent. It also appears to be an old laundry area. Maybe it’s not important but there is an active sink next to it. It has a separate drain and its own dedicated vent out the ceiling.

It will be blocking the walk way so it needs to be removed. Is it safe to cap off the entire pipe and cement over it? Anything else I should be cautious of before I proceed?

I have a licensed plumber standing by, just waiting for him to fit me into his schedule. I would love a second opinion.

[image: closed off drain]

Comment: When you remove the section of pipe, will the weight of the remaining pipe cause it to drop down...pulling it through the roof?

Comment: I would go into the attic and cut it there first.

Answer (score 1):

With it being unused I would not have called a plumber. But taken it off myself, the hard part will be the threads will be above the slab so capping flush with the concrete will be more work , you may be able to plug it With an expanding plug that would allow it to be cut off flush but it may need a gap so the plug never gets pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

It is unwise to disconnect any active drain vent. If that laundry area has a washer, sink, or anything else you need to leave it in place. If you remove it you will have problems with the laundry devices and possible other items draining properly. If the vent is in the way it can be rerouted. My best advice is do what the plumber suggestions, he is a pro and knows the codes etc in your area. You can verify my suggestions with him to be sure.

Comment: It was actually unused and previously capped off. I removed it safely, no issues with plumbing so far. Just need my plumber to come over and help me route a vent underground. (It's been tough scheduling him, everyone seems to want to be rennovating these days)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have a great week!